# Error when building DXA 2.2 Java webapp for Sites 9.5

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2, maven, sites-9.5

I have the installer for SDL DXA Java 2.2, and would like to build a webapp for Sites 9.5.  When running `prepare.bat` from PS cmdlet, I initially saw this error:

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.sdl.dxa:dxa-builder:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
   - file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
   - file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
   - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
   - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 Required by:
     project :
```

Which I got past by modifying the build.gradle config file line below to remove the snapshot ref
`classpath group: 'com.sdl.dxa', name: 'dxa-builder', version: '2.2.0-SNAPSHOT', changing: true`

When running again, I progress to the point of:

```
I am generating a scratch web application
...
= SUCCESS (in 16s): cmd /c mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeArtifactId=dxa-webapp-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sdl.dxa -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.0 -DgroupId=com.sdl.dxa -DartifactId=dxa-webapp -Dversion=2.2.0 -DskipTests=true
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
...
[INFO] Total time: 10.047 s
...
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/57M   
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dxa-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project
com.sdl.dxa:dxa-webapp:war:2.2.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.sdl.delivery:udp-common-config-legacy:jar:11.0.0-1028, com.sdl.tridion.xo:xo-compatible-
client:jar:11.0.0-1042: Could not find artifact com.sdl.delivery:udp-common-config-legacy:jar:
11.0.0-1028 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Any thoughts on what changes might be needed to get past the dependency error?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to upgrade your dependencies to
udp-common-config-legacy - 11.0.0-1051
and all others to 11.0.0-1066

Comment: I've added the dependencies explicitly to the pom.xml as noted here, issue noted is for a similar issue. However the pom.xml is in the dxa-webapp, which is wiped out when running the prepare.bat again.  Any thoughts on how to upgrade dependencies outside of the target? https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000010582

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these dependencies are missing in Maven central repos.

I would suggest to raise a ticket for it.